# Python modify text file by the name of arguments

Tags: python, replace, command

I have a text file (`"input.param"`), which serves as an input file for a package. I need to modify the value of one argument. The lines need to be changed are the following:

```
param1        0.01
model_name    run_param1
```

I need to search the argument `param1` and modify the value of `0.01` for a range of different values, meanwhile the `model_name` will also be changed accordingly for different value of `param1`. For example, if the `para1` is changed to be 0.03, then the `model_name` is changed to be 'run_param1_p03'. Below is some of my attempting code:

```
import numpy as np
import os


param1_range = np.arange(0.01,0.5,0.01)
with open('input.param', 'r') as file :
   filedata = file.read()

for p_value in param1_range:
    filedata.replace('param1        0.01', 'param1        ' + str(p_value))
    filedata.replace('model_name    run_param1', 'model_name    run_param1' + '_p0' + str(int(round(p_value*100))))

   with open('input.param', 'w') as file:
       file.write(filedata)

   os.system('./bin/run_app param/input.param')
```

However, this is not working. I guess the main problem is that the `replace` command can not recognize the `space`. But I do not know how to search the argument `param1` or `model_name` and change their values.

Comment: You are not assigning the `replace`d text to anywhere. Do `filedata = filedata.replace(..)` Note: `str.replace` doesn't do `inplace` replace

Comment: Have you looked at regex? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @hansolo Thanks, this is a good catch. I fixed that and continued to work on that.

Comment: @bison Thanks for the suggestions. I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm editing this answer to more accurately answer the original question, which it did not adequately do.

The problem is *"The `replace` command can not recognize the space"*. In order to do this, the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), or regex module, can be of great help. Your document is composed of an entry and its value, separated by spaces:

```
param1        0.01
model_name    run_param1
```

In regex, a general capture would look like so:

```py
import re

someline = 'param1        0.01'
pattern = re.match(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$', someline)

pattern.groups()
# ('param1', '0.01')
```

The regex functions as follows:

`^` captures a start-of-line
`\S` is *any* non-space char, or, anything *not* in `('\t', ' ', '\r', '\n')`
`+` indicates one or more as a greedy search (will go forward until the pattern stops matching)
`\s+` is *any* whitespace char (opposite of `\S`, note the case here)
`()` indicate groups, or how you want to group your search

The groups make it fairly easy for you to unpack your arguments into variables if you so choose. To apply this to the code you have already:

```py
import numpy as np 
import re

param1_range = np.arange(0.01,0.5,0.01)
filedata = []

with open('input.param', 'r') as file:
    # This will put the lines in a list
    # so you can use ^ and $ in the regex
    for line in file:
        filedata.append(line.strip()) # get rid of trailing newlines

# filedata now looks like:
# ['param1        0.01', 'model_name    run_param1']

# It might be easier to use a dictionary to keep all of your param vals
# since you aren't changing the names, just the values
groups = [re.match('^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$', x).groups() for x in filedata]

# Now you have a list of tuples which can be fed to dict()
my_params = dict(groups)
# {'param1': '0.01', 'model_name': 'run_param1'}

# Now just use that dict for setting your params
for p_value in param1_range:
    my_params['param1'] = str(p_value)
    my_params['model_name'] = 'run_param1_p0' + str(int(round(p_value*100)))

    # And for the formatting back into the file, you can do some quick padding to get the format you want
    with open('somefile.param', 'w') as fh:
        content = '\n'.join([k.ljust(20) + v.rjust(20) for k,v in my_params.items()])
        fh.write(content)
```

The padding is done using `str.ljust` and `str.rjust` methods so you get a format that looks like so:

```py
for k, v in dict(groups).items():
    intstr = k.ljust(20) + v.rjust(20)
    print(intstr)

param1                              0.01
model_name                    run_param1
```

Though you could arguably leave out the `rjust` if you felt so inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing it out. But the program still does not do what I want.

Comment: @HuanianZhang I've edited my answer to better reflect your question, hopefully you find it a bit more helpful

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I switch to bash shell script, which seems easier to do pattern match and replacement.